# Why is self-deception necessary to better deceive others?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, evolutionary-psychology, deception

Robert Trivers argues that we deceive ourselves in order to better deceive others, in part because self-deception can reduce unconscious body signals of lying (von Hippel & Trivers, 2011).

On Wikipedia, [self-deception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-deception) is criticized for

> ...not being able to account for why evolutionary selection for lying would allow a body language that gives away lying to exist instead of simply selecting for lack of such signals. (Ekman, 2006; Damasio, Evans & Cruse, 2004) ...

What are the main arguments against this criticism?

**References**

von Hippel, W., & Trivers, R. (2011). The evolution and psychology of self-deception. The Behavioral and brain sciences, 34(1), 1–56. https://doi.org/10.1017/S0140525X10001354

Ekman, P. (Ed.). (2006). Darwin and facial expression: A century of research in review. Ishk.

Damasio, A. R., Evans, D., & Cruse, P. (2004). Emotion, evolution and rationality. William James and the modern neurobiology of emotion, 3-14.

Comment: Is this similar to "it takes one to know one"?

Comment: for a philosophical approach, probably Sartre

Comment: The question is not related to "it takes one to know one" because self-deception is not about detecting deception in others but rather about being deceptive more effectively.